# Inserting data from one table to another using a loop

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert data from one table into another (from table [PPRS] to table [Verify]) where the Caption in PPRS is the same as in table [Master]. Someone suggested i use a loop to insert the data instead of hard coding it, however I am confused as to how to go about it.

Here's my code so far:

Declare @counter int 
declare @total int
set @counter = 0
SELECT @total =  Count(*) FROM PPRS

while @counter <= @total
    begin 
        set @counter += 1
        insert into [Verify]
        select [Task_ID],
        [Project_StartDate] ,
        [PPR_Caption],
        [Date] 
        FROM PPRS
        where [PPR_Caption] in (SELECT [Caption] from Master)

```
end
```

No data is being inserted (0 rows affected)

The sample data I'm trying to insert:

17286    01/03/2018 MP - Youth Environmental Services (12/15) 15/10/2018

Comment: What's the point of the loop?

Comment: Some sample data would help to explain your question to us.

Comment: *"i would like to use a loop"* Why? A loop is generally the **worst** option for something that (like this) can be achieved using a dataset method.

Comment: As for the reason for your error, however, I suspect that your table `Verify` has more than one column. I can't see why this is a loop anyway though, as it's simply going to run the same statement 10 times; of which the latter statements are unlikely to do anything as the relevant rows would have been inserted in the first iteration.

Comment: i want to be able to insert the data from column [PPR_Caption] in PPRS to table Verify without having to insert it manually because the records can be alot

Comment: What is "a lot"? "A lot" can be interpreted as many different things. I've seen people suggest that 10,000 rows of a couple of `int` columns defined as "a lot", but in reality that small peanuts in the World of SQL Server. you're going to need a huge amount of rows, considering you have one column, to consider this to be a performance issue in SQL Server (unless you have some awfully designed tables).

Comment: i didnt know what to use so someone suggested a loop or array , please elaborate on dataset method

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that this is along the lines of what you want to do:

```
INSERT INTO [Verify] (some_col)   -- you never told us the name of this column
SELECT TOP 10 [PPR_Caption]
FROM PPRS
WHERE [PPR_Caption] IN (SELECT [Caption] FROM MasterRecords)
ORDER BY some_column;
```

That is, you want to insert ten records into the `Verify` table, determined by some order in the source `PPRS` table.

Comment: This is probably a better way of achieving what the OP wants, but I'm pretty sure this is still going to return the error `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare specific columns to which you want to make insert. Please provide definition of table PPRS and Verify for more precise help from community.
Anyway idea please find bellow:

```
Declare @counter int 
set @counter = 0

while @counter <= 10
    begin 
        set @counter += 1
        insert into [Verify] (NameofColumn1_Table_Verify, NameofColumn2_Table_Verify,...)
        select  PPRS.NameofColumn1_Table_PPRS,
                PPRS.NameofColumn2_Table_PPRS,
                ...

        FROM PPRS
        where PPRS.[PPR_Caption] in (SELECT DISTINCT [Caption] from MasterRecords)

    end
```

Anyway I think the loop is unnecesary. One batch should make it. Please write what you want to achieve at the end.